# Electrodynamic wave energy momentum transfer

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, poynting-vector

if a point charge Q is vibrating in some mechanical way along the X axis with respect to a certain point xQ, then the value of electromagnetic energy density(which is a point function like E) on the same axis will be also oscillating. Immediately the question arises: how does the test charge q at the point of observation, lying at some
fixed distance from the point xQ along the continuation of the X-axis, “know” about thecharge Q vibration?

In other words, we have a rather strange situation: the Poynting vector S = c/4π [E × H] is zero along this axis(because H is zero along this line) but the
energy and the momentum, obviously “pass” from point to point along this axis.

Comment: How do you know they don’t pass through the off-axis space?

Comment: Empirically, this isn't too strange.  In the case of a linear dipole antenna, I believe that the transmitted power is low near/along the axis of the dipole and conversely high at right angles to the axis.  I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not asking empirically but theoretically

Comment: Do the calculation for an oscillating dipole moment. You should be able to calculate the energy-momentum tensor everywhere and see how energy flows through the field. You shouldn’t expect this calculation as an answer because I think it is a common homework problem.

Comment: I noticed that in another question you expressed a distaste for coordinates and much prefer Newton’s geometrical reasoning. If you can figure out how to do calculations like this in a coordinate-free way, I would be very interested in seeing how it compares with the conventional approach.

Comment: That's why I asked that question, not for opinions but concrete examples in which newton's geometric way fails and one must use additional structure albeit non natural, perhaps like matrix tensors in this case. Someone did point out that in some real life problems where you have complex shapes and moments of inertia one needs to resort to at least using basis vectors or something I guess, but if I spent some time I think I could solve this easily corrdinate free, I just don't know enough electromagnetism.

Answer (score 2):

The energy density at a point along the axis does vary with time in this configuration. You can see this because the magnitude of the E vector there is changing. So energy must be flowing toward and away from that point.

But it’s not flowing along the axis. Rather, it’s flowing in and out perpendicular to the axis.

Imagine a tiny loop infinitesimally away from and around the axis at the observation point. It’s so close that E is in essentially the same as the axis: radially in and out. As E is increasing outward, there’s a B field induced around the axis in a r.h.r. direction. At that time, the energy flux ExB is toward the axis: energy is flowing toward the place where the energy density is increasing.

Comment: OK I get it conceptually I think. Does it also mean I should use tensors not just a enemy momentum vector.

Comment: But shouldnt em theory also work in 1 spatial dimension?

Comment: E&M is inherently (at least) 3D; Maxwell’s equations have curls in them. Also, the Poynting vector is a _vector_. Any off it’s components might be non-zero.